# Unable to use getConnection() from datasource

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

Here's my data source configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "database1")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="database1.datasource")
public static DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

It's configured in a @Configuration class.

Here's how my application.properties looks like:

```
database1.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbpms
database1.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
database1.datasource.username=root
database1.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
database1.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
database1.datasource.initialize=true;
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

This configuration is working as expected.

My issue comes when trying to get my connection from primaryDataSource():

```
primaryDataSource().getConnection;
```

That throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1029)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109)
```

Why can't I invoke this method since my data source is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to any spring bean, you just need to autowire it to another bean, instead the invocation of method in configuration classes:

```
@Autowired
DataSource datasource;
```

Comment: That makes sense, although even invoking the method through dependency injection using @Autowired it still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally from JRichardsz answer, I believe that the correct variable name for the URL in application.properties is url, not jdbc-url.

Reference to that is in this documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.url

Comment: Good catch, although it is needed to use jdbc-url instead of url because of my MySql connector version and MySql dialect. Otherwise, datasource stop working and hibernate gets me that error: "Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove *static* modifier from primaryDataSource() method declaration. It should look like this:

```
@Bean(name = "database1")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="database1.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```